# Why shadow radius also give effect on the inside of the circle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, shadow

I want to apply shadow to the circle's outer space. But the shadow radius takes effect also on the inside, so the core circle looks smaller than it is in reality

I draw the circle like this:

```
self.shadowLayer = [CALayer layer];
self.shadowLayer.frame  = self.view.layer.bounds;
self.shadowLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
self.shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 0;
self.shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
self.shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0);
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0 , 50, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.width);
self.shadowLayer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectInset(frame, 40, 40)].CGPath;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.shadowLayer];
```

And the result is normal circle:
[image]

But if i change `self.shadowLayer.shadowRadius` from 0 to 30 the result is:
[image]

A you can see, the size of solid color in the core is shrinked. I want that shadow take effect only on the outside of the path and the solid color takes exactly the same size as in case of `shadow radius = 0`. The red curve is added afterwards the screenshot had been taken. Is there just to see the difference in size.

**UPDATE**
The one idea is to reduce `shadowRadius` by half and expand frame by the same amount. I think this will work well enough.

Comment: try giving -40,-40 for the shadowlayer as cgrectinset

Comment: it will be too large. The frame of the circle should stay the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSShadow` and draw custom `UIView` to produce the effect you want.

Draw the custom view with the code:

```
- (void)drawRect: (CGRect)frame
{
    //// General Declarations
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //// Color Declarations
    UIColor* color4 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.301 green: 0.261 blue: 0.968 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0 green: 0 blue: 0 alpha: 1];

    //// Shadow Declarations
    NSShadow* shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [shadow setShadowColor: shadowColor];
    [shadow setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0.1, -0.1)];
    [shadow setShadowBlurRadius: 11];

    //// Oval Drawing
    UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 69, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 14, 72, 70)];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadow.shadowOffset, shadow.shadowBlurRadius, [shadow.shadowColor CGColor]);
    [color4 setFill];
    [ovalPath fill];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Which gives the shadow effect at outside of the circle border:

[image]

Comment: If you're using `CGContextSetShadowWithColor` there's no need for `NSShadow`. To use the later, call the [`-[NSShadow set]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSShadow_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSShadow/set) method.

Comment: what if we want to store a reference and send it as a parameter ? Can we still do that with cgcontextsetshadowwithcolor ?